# Parse and rewrite file with python

Tags: python, parsing, file-io

Let's suppose I've the following file:

```
H  0  -15.7284260000000       -16.4229420000000       0.364919000000000 
H  0  -16.4853770000000       -15.1118660000000       0.364919000000000 
O  0  -17.9378060000000       -14.2325190000000       0.944687000000000 
H  0  -18.7307670000000       -14.6487540000000       0.606761000000000 
H  0  -17.9738160000000       -13.3376780000000       0.606761000000000 
H  0  -17.1677320000000       -11.1468579990000       0.307511000000000 
...
```

And the following list containing the number of line in the file, grouped under certain criteria: `index = [[1,3][4,7][2,5,6]]`.

I want to rewrite the file adding a label to each line according the supposed criteria, i.e. lines 1 and 3 will get the label 'H', lines 4,7  the label 'M' and lines 2,5,6 the label 'L', to obtain the file:

```
H  0  -15.7284260000000       -16.4229420000000       0.364919000000000 H
H  0  -16.4853770000000       -15.1118660000000       0.364919000000000 L
O  0  -17.9378060000000       -14.2325190000000       0.944687000000000 H
H  0  -18.7307670000000       -14.6487540000000       0.606761000000000 M
H  0  -17.9738160000000       -13.3376780000000       0.606761000000000 L
H  0  -17.1677320000000       -11.1468579990000       0.307511000000000 L
H  0  -10.3904079990000       -10.7642359990000       0.664160000000000 M 
...
```

I'm using the following code, but I'm not able to include the needed conditions in the `write()` method, any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
try:
   input_file = open(file, 'r')
   input = input_file.readlines()
   print 'Input file \"' + file + '\" was read'
except:
   error_mssg = 'Please provide an input file'
   sys.exit(error_mssg)

with open('output.com','w') as output:
      while ii<=len(input)-1:
        if(input[ii].strip()==''):
           break
        output.write(input[ii].strip()+' H'+'\n')
        ii = ii + 1
```

Comment: What aren't you able to do?

Comment: `i.e. lines 1 and 3 will get the label 'H', lines 4,7 the label 'M' and so on, to obtain the file`, how did you decide H/M ? What will line `[2,5,6]` get and on what criteria ?

Comment: I can't select a certain label according to the data in the list, and add it to the line in question. It's just an example, sorry if it's not clear, lines [2,5,6] will get another label.

Comment: @Panadestein `[2,5,6] will get another label` how do you decide this another label? is it just any arbitrary label ?

Comment: @Vikash Singh I edited the question in order to make it more clear, I hope it's fine now.

Comment: @Panadestein I added a solution based on your input. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = 'input.txt'

try:
    input_file = open(file, 'r')
    input_lines = input_file.readlines()
    print('Input file \"' + file + '\" was read')
except:
    error_mssg = 'Please provide an input file'
    sys.exit(error_mssg)

index_mapping = {'H': [1,3],
                 'M': [4,7],
                 'L': [2,5,6]}

index_mapping_reversed = {val : key for key in index_mapping for val in index_mapping[key]}

index_mapping_reversed
# {1: 'H', 2: 'L', 3: 'H', 4: 'M', 5: 'L', 6: 'L', 7: 'M'}

with open('output.txt','w') as output:
    for idx, line in enumerate(input_lines):
        suffix = ''
        if idx + 1 in index_mapping_reversed:
            suffix = ' ' + index_mapping_reversed.get(idx + 1, '')
        output.write(line.strip() + suffix + '\n')
```

output.txt:

```
H  0  -15.7284260000000       -16.4229420000000       0.364919000000000 H
H  0  -16.4853770000000       -15.1118660000000       0.364919000000000 L
O  0  -17.9378060000000       -14.2325190000000       0.944687000000000 H
H  0  -18.7307670000000       -14.6487540000000       0.606761000000000 M
H  0  -17.9738160000000       -13.3376780000000       0.606761000000000 L
H  0  -17.1677320000000       -11.1468579990000       0.307511000000000 L
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest approach for you will be to perform some middle processing before you write the lines back out.

You want to append a character to each line in a list, given several combinations of list/character pairings:

```
def append_char(text, char, lines):
    """Given a list of text lines, text, a char, and a list of line
    numbers, lines, append the char to each line identified by number.
    Note that line numbers start at 1, while text indexes start at 0.
    """
    for l in lines:
        text[l-1] += ' ' + char
```

Then to run this, do:

```
letters = 'HM'

for i, ch in enumerate(letters):
    append_char(input, ch, index[i])
```

Be aware, if there are any collisions you will get 'blah H M' and not 'blah HM', if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = { 0 : 'H',
      1 : 'H',
      2 : 'M',
    }
def ending(i):
    return d.get(i, '') + '\n'

with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('output.txt', 'w+') as o:
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        o.write('{}{}'.format(line, ending(i)))
```

Here's one way to do it.  Here, we encapsulate the logic for determining the ending of the lines in the function `ending`.  If you know before hand which lines need to be changed, you can use a dictionary solution like this one.  If it requres some calculation (say based on the line itself), then rewrite `ending` to reflect that, making sure that it accepts as arguments all the information necessary to determine the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You have no reason to read everything in memory: it will not speed up anything an could only waste memory if you had to process a big file.

I could not understand how you managed to obtain the magic values `'H'` and `'M'`, so I assumed they were given in the `index` array, and I preprocess that array to obtain a map {line_number: label}. Then I simply have to read input lines one at a time with their number, and add the label if one exists:

```
index = [([1,3], 'H'), ([4,7], 'M'), ([2,5,6], None)]

def preprocess(index):
    h = {}
    for elt in index:
        if elt[1] is not None:
            for num in elt[0]: h[num] = elt[1]
    return h

with open(file, 'r') as inputfile:
    with open('output.com','w') as output:
        h = preprocess(index)
        for num, line in enumerate(inputfile, 1):
            if num in h: line = line.rstrip() + " " + h[num] + "\n"
            dummy = output.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the question that I posted is just a part of a bigger problem. However, maybe you are right and I don't have to load everything in memory, I will check.